# Spring Boot Enum Custom Validation not working with Jakarta

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, bean-validation

Following is my custom validator

```
package my.dtos.enums;

import my.dtos.CourseStatus;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CourseStatusValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CourseStatusType, CourseStatus> {
    private CourseStatus[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CourseStatusType constraint) {
        this.subset = constraint.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CourseStatus value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }
}
```

Here is the annotation

```
package my.dtos.enums;

import my.dtos.CourseStatus;
import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;


import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;


@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CourseStatusValidator.class)
public @interface CourseStatusType {
    CourseStatus[] anyOf();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

HEre is how I am using it in one my DTO

```
@CourseStatusType(anyOf = {CourseStatus.PENDING, CourseStatus.CANCELED})
private CourseStatus status;
```

The validation is not working its not being applied and I am seeing an exception realted to parsing of data
`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type` com.some.path.CourseStatus`from String "WRONG_DATA_PASSWED": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [CANCELED, DONE, IN_PROGRESS, PENDING]`

Following is the controller method

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Course update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody @Validated CourseRequest request)
```

> I want it to apply my validation and throw error according to that
> validation

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, the problem is that you are trying to send the data that cannot be parsed into your enum. The way things works is that first, your request body is parsed into the `CourseRequest` class, and then ***if*** the parsing is successful -- Bean Validation will apply.

If you want to use Bean Validation for checking that the string sent is valid - consider changing the `CourseRequest` where instead of an enum make that field a `String` this way parsing will not fail. Then you can use a `@Pattern` constraint to apply a regex check to that field to make sure that only acceptable strings are sent.

Then you can just have a getter in your `CourseRequest` that would convert the string to an enum to use it elsewhere:

```java
class CourseRequest {
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(PENDING|CANCELED)$")
    String status;

    public CourseStatus courseStatus() {
        return status == null ? null : CourseStatus.valueOf( status );
    }
}
```